# Show content,sest session. After session ended show content again ect.. PHP

Tags: php, session, splash-screen

I know it's simple, but i cannot get it work.
I want to show content once to any user that visits website and set session, while session exists,content is hidden, afters session ends, content apears and session is set again for half hour.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["timeout"])){
     $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
};
$st = $_SESSION['timeout'] + (30 * 60); 

if(time() > $st){
    ?>
    <div class="promotion" id="hide">
        <span class="closead"  onclick ="javascript:ShowHide('hide')" ></span>
        <div class="promotion_bg">
            <h2>Hello!</h2>
            <p>Blah blah blah</p>
        </div>
        <span class="promotion_btn" onclick="location.href='register.php';">
            Register!
        </span>
    </div>
    <?php 
     $_SESSION['timeout'] = time() + (30 * 60);
}
?>
```

So i tried to do debug and came with code like this.

```
    <?php
if(isset($_SESSION['timeout'])){
    if(time() > $_SESSION['timeout']){
        echo '<h1>Unsetting session</h1>';
            session_unset($_SESSION['timeout']);
    }
}
echo $_SESSION['timeout'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['timeout'])){
    echo '<h1>Session is not set</h1>';
     $_SESSION['timeout'] = time() + 60;
}
?>
```

And my mind i am struggling, this dosn't make sence, how it's posiible that its validates 
!isset part if its throws me an error `Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in D:\xampp\htdocs\...\test.php on line 9`

when i am trying  to echo it just echo it.

Comment: Well, you have just static HTML between your PHP tags. Remove those inner tags and do echo() for displaying all that HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code work for me!. When session exists content is hidden when session is end content has appeard for one second and then session is set again. But first content show is after half hour.

Be sure if session is already started. At the top of code you shuold call

```
  session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['promotion'])){
    ?>
    <div class="promotion" id="hide">
        <span class="closead"  onclick ="javascript:ShowHide('hide')" ></span>
        <div class="promotion_bg">
            <h2>Hello!</h2>
            <p>Blah blah blah</p>
        </div>
        <span class="promotion_btn" onclick="location.href='register.php';">
            Register!
        </span>
    </div>
    <?php 
    $_SESSION['promotion'] = 1;
}
?>
```

Comment: it's not working. I need to show content only once and then set the session, and hide content for all time, while session is set.

Comment: I thought you wanted it to show every 30 minutes. Check the modified code. When user logs out and in, it will show again.